# How do I print a url path in an `a` tag using the url's name attribute?

Tags: django

In my `urls.py` I have `url("^login-register/$", views.login_register, name="login_register"),`.

In a template, I can do `{% url "login_register" %}`. How do I `print` that value in `views.py`?

Comment: That's [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `views.py` file, you can use the [reverse method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

> If you need to use something similar to the **url** template tag in your code, Django provides the following function:
>
> `reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)`
>
> **viewname** can be a URL pattern name or the callable view object.

You can use this in any python module, including `views.py`:

```py
from django.urls import reverse

def print_login_register_url():
    url = reverse('login_register')
    print(url)
```